# moved underwater

Tags: meaning, adverbs

a. The submarine moved underwater.

b. The submarine ran underwater.

c. The submarine went underwater.

Do these mean

1. It was above the surface of the water and then went below it

or

2. It was moving under the surface of the water

?

Many thanks

Comment: We usually say submarines ***dive*** when they go down from sea level, and ***surface*** when they come back up. To ***sink*** usually implies "not deliberately" (ship or submarine breached by a torpedo in warfare, for example), but *The submarine sank beneath the waves* could refer to a deliberate nautical manoeuvre OR  the result of a damaging attack.

Comment: But none of your example texts seem like things a native speaker would say, so it's not really worth "analysing" them.

Comment: We don't speak of a submarine running. To _go underwater_ could mean to submerge (dive), and to _move under [the] water_ could mean to move along under the surface - but, as FumbleFingers says, these are not natural ways to express these ideas.

Comment: @KateBunting - There is a very famous submarine movie titled *Run Silent, Run Deep*, so I do believe that at least at some point in time submarines were described as *running.*  I found a definition at Oxford -- *(of a boat) sail directly before the wind, especially in bad weather.*  A submarine, being a boat, probably uses some variation of this definition to mean *move*.

Comment: submerged cruising. You will find everything you need here: https://maritime.org/doc/subphrase/index.php A submarine cruises underwater.

Comment: The classic science fiction film Silent Running was a reference to submarines running quietly to avoid detection.

Comment: With some additional research I think I have solved the mystery of of what is meant by *running* as it applies to submarines.  *Running*  is the condition of the submarine operating under battery power.  This would explain the reference to *silence* in the title *Run Silent, Run Deep*.    The example I found applies specifically to WWII submarines.  https://www.usscod.org/def.html.  See *running dive*.

Answer (score 2):

It's impossible to know without more information. All three can be used to describe a submarine in motion while submerged. However, to my ear, the last sentence with "went" somewhat implies a transition, more than "ran" and "moved" do.

In all three cases, the addition of a word or two would make it clearer:

These say that the submarine is already submerged and moving:

*The submarine moved ahead underwater.*

*The submarine ran silently underwater.*

*The submarine went forward underwater.*

On the other hand, these sentences suggest more strongly that the submarine went from being on the surface to submerged:

*The submarine moved, going underwater.*

*The submarine ran to underwater.*

*The submarine went down, underwater.*